# chrome extension option page local storage set and get

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, get, set, local-storage

I am trying to develop a chrome extension, and when developing the option page it could not be restored successfully. I have read several posting, but didn't quite understand. 
Really appreciate if someone could help.

```
var x = document.getElementById("X-Frame");

function saveOptions(){
if(x.checked){
 chorme.storage.local.set({"X-Frame":"true"},function(){
                console.log("x-frame saved");
                });
 }

}


function callOptions(){
chrome.storage.local.get("X-Frame", function(obj){
                         if(obj.X-Frame === "true"){
                         document.getElementById("X-Frame").checked = true;
                         }
                         })

}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callOptions);
document.getElementById("saveOptions").addEventListener('click',saveOptions);
```

Comment: `obj.X-Frame` is `obj.X - Frame` (subtraction). Use `obj['X-Frame']` instead. Look at the documentation for a good example: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options

Comment: Thank you so much Rob, this do work.